# ColdFusion scheduler threads eating CPU

Tags: coldfusion, jvm, tomcat7, cpu-usage

I've got CF10 running on a dev box, Windows 7, 64 bit.
Periodically, every minute or so, the CPU usage for CF10 will spike up to 100% for about 20 seconds and come back down. It's pretty regular.

I've found it difficult to diagnose this issue. I've seen talk of client variables purges, logging, monitoring and all manner of things - but I've turned these all off to no avail.

With VisualVM, I've managed to track the issue down to the 'scheduler' threads. I have 5 of these in a waiting state. Periodically each will run, bumping up the CPU dramatically.
Taking a thread dump, it seems that all these threads are calling `java.io.WinNTFileSystem.getBooleanAttributes` - something I've seen mentioned a few times as potentially problematic.

**UPDATE:** Recently I've been playing with onSessionEnd on another app, and discovered that the `scheduler-x` threads appear to be internal to ColdFusion - my onSessionEnd tasks always seem to run in one of these threads.

Looking in the temp folder, I can see that a lot of EH Cache folders have been made which I think are to do with query caching. The apps I have running make use of this fairly extensively. I thought clearing the temp folder out might improve performance but it has had no effect.

It's worth noting that if I start the CF service without actually calling any of my apps, the problem does not occur. That might suggest the issue is with the apps themselves, however they do not cause any issue in production - only on this box.
There are no scheduled tasks set up either.

Below is an example of one of the threads causing high CPU. I'd appreciate any help in diagnosing what this thread is doing and why, as well as how to potentially stop it from using so much resources.

```
"scheduler-2" - Thread t@84
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
    at java.io.WinNTFileSystem.getBooleanAttributes(Native Method)
    at java.io.File.isDirectory(File.java:849)
    at coldfusion.watch.Watcher.accept(Watcher.java:352)
    at java.io.File.listFiles(File.java:1252)
    at coldfusion.watch.Watcher.getFiles(Watcher.java:386)
    at coldfusion.watch.Watcher.getFiles(Watcher.java:397)
    at coldfusion.watch.Watcher.getFiles(Watcher.java:397)
    at coldfusion.watch.Watcher.getFiles(Watcher.java:397)
    at coldfusion.watch.Watcher.getFiles(Watcher.java:397)
    at coldfusion.watch.Watcher.getFiles(Watcher.java:397)
    at coldfusion.watch.Watcher.getFiles(Watcher.java:397)
    at coldfusion.watch.Watcher.getFiles(Watcher.java:397)
    at coldfusion.watch.Watcher.getFiles(Watcher.java:397)
    at coldfusion.watch.Watcher.getFiles(Watcher.java:397)
    at coldfusion.watch.Watcher.checkWatchedDirectories(Watcher.java:166)
    at coldfusion.watch.Watcher.run(Watcher.java:216)
    at coldfusion.scheduling.ThreadPool.run(ThreadPool.java:211)
    at coldfusion.scheduling.WorkerThread.run(WorkerThread.java:71)
```

**My environment:**

- Win 7 64-bit
- CF10 Update 12
- JDK 1.8.0_11

The issue occurs on multiple versions of JVM - this version is currently used to make monitoring available.

**My java settings:**

- Min heap size: 512mb
- Max heap size: 1024mb

  -server -XX:MaxPermSize=512m -XX:+UseParallelGC -Xbatch -Dcoldfusion.home={application.home} -Dcoldfusion.rootDir={application.home} -Dcoldfusion.libPath={application.home}/lib -Dorg.apache.coyote.USE_CUSTOM_STATUS_MSG_IN_HEADER=true -Dcoldfusion.jsafe.defaultalgo=FIPS186Random -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=8701 -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false

I'd be lying if I said I understood what all of these settings do!
Sorry if you're one of those people that believes all CF developers should be Java app stack experts. I am not. 
Any help, much appreciated. ;)

Comment: I've worked some years with ColdFusion and like you i'm no expert on Java app stack. Last time i made extensive use of CFThread i tried to set the max heap size on 2GB, that solved all the issues. Nonetheless, my first guess from the error stack would be that Windows encountered a corrupted/nonexisting file, or the CFThread user has issues with R/W authorization.

Comment: Thanks for the input. I'm not actually using CFThread in these apps - the threads I've narrowed it down to appear to be internal to ColdFusion as far as I can see. In fact, running on a dev box I can be pretty certain that no requests are being made to the app whatsoever when the issue occurs. There are no scheduled tasks running in the background, nothing keeping sessions alive - I can let the app time out completely and the server is still hitting 100% many hours later!

Comment: Do you have a DirectoryWatcher configured? if so, does it watch a local directory/network mapped directory?

Comment: No, I don't have a DirectoryWatcher configured - at least as far as I can tell. I've never used it, or indeed heard of it until now. I looked in the event gateway section of the administrator but there's nothing active in there.
I do have some code that uses DirectoryList, FileExists and GetFileInfo - however none of that runs on a schedule and as I said above, there doesn't have to be requests running for the issue to occur.

Comment: I would definitely suspect the ColdFusion event gateway. There is a sample gateway that comes with ColdFusion - [DirectoryWatcher Watches a directory for file changes.](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/10.0/Admin/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbf3638e6-7fce.html#WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbf3638e6-7fcc). If you are not using the event gateway option then disable it completely in the administrator. I believe there is a checkbox that is _enabled_ by default. Go to the Gateway Instances page and stop all from running. Change their startup mode to manual. Even delete them entirely if you wish.

Comment: @Gary This part of the stacktrace - coldfusion.watch.Watcher.checkWatchedDirectories(Watcher.java:166) - made me suspect this is the directory watcher.

Comment: I'd thought the same thing when I saw the stacktrace, but I've checked the administrator. The only event gateway set up in there is an example SMS gateway and there's no tick in the 'Enable ColdFusion Event Gateway Services' box in the Event Gateway settings page.
Unless there's an issue with CF's ability to read that setting, I don't think this can be the cause.

Comment: Just to be absolutely sure, I've now deleted the DirectoryWatcher gateway type (there were no instances of it) from the CF admin. Still no change though. I think the gateway type must be used internally for other reasons. I have added a class path in the Application.cfc - I wonder if this would trigger an event to see if any changes have been made. I can't easily get the app to boot without this, so no real way to test. Can anyone confirm or deny this assertion?

Comment: Is your ColdFusion administrator set to `Watch configuration files for changes (check every nn seconds)`?  That is the only other option I can think of that may _watch_ a directory for changes.

Comment: No, that's not ticked either...

Comment: *sigh* - So this morning I fired up the instance and lo and behold, all the 'scheduler-x' threads were missing. I suppose that means something I tried yesterday must have worked, but I'm not sure what it could have been.
The directory watcher gateway type still exists in production, so deleting that on the dev box shouldn't have fixed the issue...

Comment: I'd still appreciate some suggestions on diagnosing this issue. Today some of the scheduler tasks are back and I've no idea why.
I'm thinking there must be something wrong in the folder that is being 'watched', but I've absolutely no way of finding out what folder that could be!

Comment: We are also having this issue if you ever resolved it.

Comment: I'm afraid not. I did see something recently that lead me to believe these were spooler tasks for sending email - but I have no mail in the spool so not sure it's relevant to the issue.

Comment: @GaryStanton I was also able to confirm that these threads are used for log management in addition to spool. We also had this happen on an idle server and were thinking that anti-virus might have had a lock on a file or something.

Comment: I imagine there is a setting in CF that amounts to telling it to watch the filesystem for changes to application files? If so, is that setting set to "dont watch"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using FusionReactor 6, I was able to solve this for us today. We were using `this.javaSettings` to hot load java class files. The `WatchInterval` from `this.javaSettings` uses the `DirectoryWatcher` at the specified watch number. In our case, I had lowered it to one second.

How I solved it: I set a breakpoint in FusionReactor and could see that it was constantly stuck scanning the directory above the one I specified in `this.javasettings`. This directory has enough files and subfolders, that it looks like one `DirectoryWatcher` was unable to finish before the next one was created. Had ColdFusion just stuck to the subfolder, I specified in `this.javaSettings`, it would not have been a problem.

Example:

```
This.javaSettings       = {
          loadPaths                 = ["\externals\lib\"]
        , loadColdFusionClassPath   = true
        , reloadOnChange            = true
        , watchInterval             = 1
};
```

In the above case, lib has just 5 files. However, "externals" is loaded with stuff. In the breakpoint, it was typically looking at stuff in "externals."

Comment: That could very well be the issue! I am using javasettings on all of my apps - though I don't specify a watch interval. I do have `reloadOnChange` set though.
Unfortunately, I no longer have the box that exhibited the problem - so I'm not readily able to test the theory. Sounds likely though!

Comment: Yeah, and it seems to me that it does this per application. So, given then default of 60 seconds, if you had a lot of apps scanning a large directory, it could very well do it.

Comment: Well, the directory being scanned only contains a couple of files - but if, as you say, it's scanning directories /above/ the one specified, that would explain the issue. Sounds like a bug to me - can you submit it, if you have evidence?

Comment: I could not confirm this to be a "bug" after looking at the underlying java code and hanging around in the stack traces. However, I would certainly qualify it as a "warning" setting. With too low of a watch interval or too many apps with the default, you are going to get locks causing the watches to stack and block.

Comment: I'm just assuming that if the DirectoryWatcher is scanning a folder *above* the one specified in the javaSettings, that can't be desired behaviour, can it?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have scheduled tasks running that use the CFFILE tag? They tend to be resource hogs. Spinning these into their own threads may help with the CPU spike.

another thought:

looking at the JVM,

```
•Min heap size: 512mb
•Max heap size: 1024mb
```

These establish the minimum and maximum memory available to the java virtual machine

```
-server -XX:MaxPermSize=512m
```

This is the amount of memory dedicated to the java permanent memory generation.

you've got half of your JVM allocated memory dedicated to the permanent generation, try bumping up the maximum heap size to 2048mb. and restarting the ColdFusion service. It could go higher based on whether or not you're running a 64Bit operating system or not.

Comment: There are no scheduled tasks at all.